# regex result to have only 2 decimals

Tags: regex

I have this regex and I want the result to have 2 decimals the most, how can I do this.
The source is `price":"7.3500000000000005","availability` and the regex rule is this

```
@price":"(.*)","availability@U
```

The result is 7.3500000000000005, I want the result to be 7.35.

Thank you for the help

Comment: What do you understand `*` to mean in a regex?

Comment: * give all "string" I want only 2 decimals. Thank you

Comment: Do you know a pattern that matches a single decimal?

Comment: What programming language are you using for regex?

Comment: I have a console and I need a regex rule, I am new at regex.

Comment: Try replacing `(.*)` with `(.*?\...)`

Comment: I tried this but it does not work (inside the (.*) [0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[^0-9]

Comment: @Bohemian,it seems that  it does not work

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: The one you wrote will only match numbers with exactly two decimal places and skip all other numbers. Try `\d+(\.\d{,2})?`. Which will allow integers, numbers with one decimal place, numbers with two and all others will be cut off after two digits (note that it does just cut off and not round them properly though!). Generally regex is not a good way to handle decimal precision, better to convert it into a proper number format and use whatever programming language you are working with to do it.

Comment: You probably want `@price":"\K\d+\.\d{2}(?=[^"]*","availability)@`. Another idea: `@price":"\K\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?=[^"]*","availability)@`

Comment: Try replacing `(.*)` with `(.*?\...).*`

Comment: I was given this @price":"(\d+(?>\.\d{0,2})?).*?","availability@

Comment: Do not rely on `.*?`, it may overmatch.

Comment: This seems like a rather bad assignment for using regular expressions. Any decent language should have simple functions to extract sub-strings from larger strings, as well ad functions to find the position of specific characters or to split a string into a list of sub-strings using a specific separator. By splitting the input string at the colon `:` you can then get the sub-string containing the number. Skip the leading `"`, find the dot `.`, and get two more characters, and you have the sub-string you want. This might even be more effective than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Regex:

```
price":"(\d+\.\d{2})
```

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/Ca3W2I/1